# echo $_POST[valuename] not being read

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm new to ajax and I'm having some trouble getting it to work.

The code is supposed to send 2 variables to PHP from a javascript. And then just echo it back in a string. But am only getting generic text from the PHP but where the variables should be are left empty.

My javascript

```
function ok_press() {
    var tjeck_login = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    users_name = 'jon'; 
    users_password = 'password';
    users_infor = "usersname="+users_name+"&userspassword="+users_password;
    tjeck_login.open ("POST", "php/test.php",true);
    tjeck_login.setRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    tjeck_login.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (tjeck_login.readyState == 4 ){            

        if (tjeck_login.status >= 200 && tjeck_login.status <300 || tjeck_login.status == 304){
          var output = tjeck_login.responseText;
          alert(users_infor);
          alert(output);
        }
      }
    }

    tjeck_login.send(users_infor);
}
```

And my php code is

```
<?php

echo 'Hello ' . $_POST['usersname'] . ' your passeword is ' . $_POST['userspassword'];

?>
```

But what it spits out is only 
"Hello your passeword is" but what it should say is "Hello jon your passeword is password.

Comment: I would recommend using the fetch api (depending on your compatibility requirements): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

Comment: you use $_REQUEST method instead

Comment: I hope you're not actually sending passwords in plaintext! :)

Comment: @tobiv nothing wrong with that (over SSL of course). Storing them as plain text is a problem though

Comment: So you're saying you get two JavaScript alerts, one with `usersname=jon&userspassword=password` and the other with `Hello your passeword is`?

Comment: jjoselon I tried to replace $_POST in the php file with $_REQUEST, but the problem was still the same.

Comment: tobiv No am just trying to learn ajax it just for texting, so i chould also just have called it email or lastname or something. It did not really matter

Comment: @Phil the    [usersname=jon&userspassword=password] alart is just to tjek if the input was correct. The problem is only the    [Hello your passeword is] which am trying get to say [Hello jon your password is password]

Comment: Yes, I understand that but you didn't answer my question... Are you seeing the two alerts, one after the other with the text appearing exactly as outlined in my original question?

Answer (score -2):

If you are creating a string in PHP within quotes then you cannot use quotes in your variable arrays.

Change this:

```
echo 'Hello ' . $_POST['usersname'] . ' your passeword is ' . $_POST['userspassword'];
```

To this:

```
echo "Hello {$_POST['usersname']} your passeword is {$_POST['userspassword']}";
```

Comment: Does not work, i get a error in the alart window saying <br /> <b> Parse error </br>: syntax error, unexpected'{', expecting ',' or ';' in <b>/ (the url for the file) </b> on line <b> 3 </b><br/>

Comment: My bad, you should change the quotes around the string to double quotes. So echo "Hello {$_POST['usersname']} your passeword is {$_POST['userspassword']}";